# Foundation 6.2 Slider set value with js

Tags: javascript, slider, zurb-foundation

I'd like to set a value of Slider with javascript, but I don't know how to do it. I tried to modify a value of hidden input but the slider handle does not move.

my HTML:

```
 <div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="50" data-step="5">
    <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" ></span>
    <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
    <input type="hidden"> 
  </div>
```

Please, help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to set the value on page load via javascript or via some action e.g. a click?

Comment: I want to set the value when focus event is fired.

Answer (score 2):

Hi when you move the slider handle the new value gets set into the hidden input.
But changing the value of the hidden input will not move the slider.

So you can do this:

`var pos = 5;
 mySlider = new Foundation.Slider( $("#my_slider"), {initialStart: pos});`

Comment: It works. Thank You! But, it seems to be not very elegant solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for a bit and the real key is that you need to do three things:

1. Create the slider with a hidden input field
2. Set the value of the input field to the new position
3. Trigger a change event on the field

Here's a simple example showing it working.

```js
$(document).foundation();
function jumpto(val) {
   $("#exslider input").val(val).trigger('change');
}
// Just for grins, jump to a fixed location at the start.
jumpto(33);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.6.3/dist/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Compressed CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.6.3/dist/css/foundation.min.css" integrity="sha256-ogmFxjqiTMnZhxCqVmcqTvjfe1Y/ec4WaRj/aQPvn+I=" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Compressed JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.6.3/dist/js/foundation.min.js" integrity="sha256-pRF3zifJRA9jXGv++b06qwtSqX1byFQOLjqa2PTEb2o=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="grid-x">
  <div class="cell">
    <label>This shows setting the values of a foundation slider without having to recreate the slider.
    The key is that the hidden input automatically gets associated with the slider value.
    Setting the value is not enough to cause it to be updated, it is necessary to trigger the change
    event so that foundation knows to update the slider.
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="slider" id="exslider" data-slider data-end="100">
      <span class="slider-handle" data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="sliderVal"></span>
      <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
      <input type="hidden">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
  <div class="button-group">
  <a class="button" onclick="jumpto(5);">Jump to 5</a>
  <a class="button" onclick="jumpto(50);">Jump to 50</a>
  <a class="button" onclick="jumpto(100);">Jump to 100</a>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the type of input from hidden and add aria-controls="id" to the slider handle and "id" is the ID of the input - the input can be anywhere on the page, then now you just have to change the value of the input with javascript

```
<div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="50" data-step="5">
    <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="myInputId" ></span>
    <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
    <input type="number" id="myInputId"> 
</div>


document.getElementById("myInputId").value = "99";
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Shame really, that would be elegant.  The slider doesn't move just by changing the input value